# Finding the Laurent series when a residue at $z=0$ is given

Tags: laurent-series

I have $a_n=\frac{1}{n^4+1}$, where *n* is an integer. I want to determine the Laurent series for a function f(z) such that the residue for $\frac{f(z)}{z^n}$ in $z=0$ is $a_n \forall \ n$.

Based on this introduction, I start with  that:

\begin{equation}
Res_{z=0}\frac{f(z)}{z^n}=\frac{1}{n^4+1}
\end{equation}

and:

\begin{equation}
Res_{z=0} \frac{f(z)}{z^n}=\lim_{z\longrightarrow 0}(z-0)\frac{f(z)}{z^n}=\frac{1}{n^4+1}
\end{equation}

I write it out as:

\begin{equation}
Res_{z=0} \frac{f(z)}{z^n}=\lim_{z\longrightarrow 0}(z-0)\frac{f(z)}{(z-0)^n}=\lim_{z\longrightarrow 0}\frac{f(z)}{(z)^{n-1}}=\frac{1}{n^4+1}
\end{equation}

Then I take that this equation (eqn. 1)

\begin{equation}
\lim_{z\longrightarrow 0}\frac{f(z)}{(z)^{n-1}}=\frac{1}{n^4+1}
\end{equation}

is the key to find the Laurent series (eqn.2 ):

\begin{equation}
f(z)=...+\frac{a_{-2}}{(z-z_0)^2}+\frac{a_{-1}}{(z-z_0)}+a_0+a_1(z-z_0)+a_2(z-z_0)^2+...a_n(z-z_0)^n
\end{equation}

But how can I solve this using eqn.  1 and 2?

UPDATE:

I use the formula for the Laurent Series:

\begin{equation}
f(z)=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^4+1}(z-z_0)^n
\end{equation}

Since at residue $z=0$ we have $\frac{f(z)}{z}$, I have the following:

\begin{equation}
\frac{f(z)}{z}=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^4+1}\frac{(z-z_0)^n}{(z-z_0)}=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^4+1}(z^{n-1})
\end{equation}

This would give the proposed form of the Laurent series with residue z=0 as given:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(z^{n-1})}{n^4+1}
\end{equation}

Inserting for $k=n-1$ we get

\begin{equation}
\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(z^{k})}{(k+1)^4+1}
\end{equation}

Would that be correct?

Comment: Instead of $Res(0)$, you should write $\operatorname{Res}_{z=0}\frac{f(z)}{z^n}$. Also, the introduction of $z_0$ is unnecessary.

Comment: Done. Can you comment on the actual result?

Comment: I can: it does not make any sense. $f(z) \neq \sum \frac{1}{n^4+1}z^n$.

Comment: According to Kavis answer, the right answer is $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^4+1}z^{n-k}$

Comment: The right answer for what?

Comment: Please read the title of the post

Comment: The claim in that answer is $$
f(z) = \sum\limits_{k =  - \infty }^\infty  {\frac{{z^k }}{{(k + 1)^4  + 1}}} .
$$

Comment: So, what is the answer, since Kavi gave only a generalized form? If I can see the answer, maybe I can understand more. This seems like I am wasting time trying, to find the answer by asking, even though I have made a proposition

Comment: Kavi gave a proper answer to the question you posed in the first two lines. Whether or not you understand it is a different story. To me it looks like a simple and straightforward answer.

Comment: This is a waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

If the Laurent series  of $f(z)$ around $0$ is $ \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} b_kz^{k}$ then the Laurent series for $\frac {f(z)} {z^{n}}$ is  $ \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} b_kz^{k-n}$ and the residue at $z=0$  is simply the coefficient of $\frac 1 z$. So $a_n=b_{n-1}$ Thus $b_n=a_{n+1}=\frac 1 {(n+1)^{4}+1}$ for all $n$.

Comment: Minor point: $a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{(n+1)^4+1}$

Comment: @Gary Yes, of course. Thanks!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy How do you go from the Laurent form of  $f(z)/z^n$ to 1/z and then from 1/z to the final form?

Comment: @ViolaPlayer Do you know that the residue at $0$ is precisely the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ in the Laurent series? What is the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ in $
\sum\nolimits_{k =  - \infty }^\infty  {b_k z^{k - n} } $?

Comment: 1, it seems. ..

Comment: @ViolaPlayer Incorrect. Do you know the meaning of $\sum\nolimits_{k =  - \infty }^\infty b_k z^{k - n}$? Do you understand the summation notation? If you are studying complex analyis, this should be easy, because these concepts appear much earlier in one's mathematical studies.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I will take this elsewhere.